# как создать эффект сетки реагирующей на мышь по примеру сайта?

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas, background, webgl

Всем привет. Подскажите, как реализовать подобный эффект: сетку, реагирующую на наведение мыши, как это сделано [здесь](https://leveltradingfield.com/#contact) уже второй раз встречаю подобное, но реализации, логично, никто не раскрывает. Максимально приближенное - это либа [particles.js](http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/), но то ли у меня не хватает скиллов всё грамотно настроить, то ли это немного другое. CodePen уже облазил весь, есть схожее тут codepen.io/soulwire/pen/Ffvlo, но там частицы не полностью восстанавливают первоначальную структуру после размазывания их мышью - остаётся след. Буду благодарен за подсказки, да и другим может пригодиться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на гифке плохо видно, но точки соединены линиями в сетку

Comment: я собрал, как мне показалось, что-то похожее, попозже докручу до ума, и обновлю ответ, самая актуальная версия пока на codepen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Реализовал нечто похожее на WebGL, при помощи вершинного шейдера

ps: неплохо бы прикрутить какую нибудь функцию сглаживания к значению burst.

UPD: убрал шум, там больше похоже на эффект по ссылке, однако чтобы сделать эффект рисования, это уже будет не 100 строчек..

самая актуальна версия тут: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/xoZeGQ

```html
<canvas width="300" height="300" id="canvas" style="background-color:black;"/>
<script type=" " id="vert">
  attribute vec2 v;
  uniform vec2 mouse;
  uniform float time;   
  uniform float burst; 
    
  void main(void) {
    gl_PointSize = 2.7;
    vec2 p = v;
    vec2 m = mouse*2. - 1.;    
    vec2 r = p - m;
    if (dot(r,r) < .1) {
     float a = atan(r.y, r.x);
      vec2 p1 = m+vec2(cos(a),sin(a))*.3;
      p = mix(p, p1, burst);
    }
    gl_Position = vec4(p, 0., 1.);
  }
</script>
<script type=" " id="frag">
  precision highp float;

  void main(void) {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(.8, .8, .8, 1.);  
  }
</script>
<script>
let active = false, burst = 0, size = 22, vertices = [];
for (var x=0; x<size; x++) for (var y=0; y<size; y++) 
  vertices.push(1/size + x*2/size - 1, 1/size + y*2/size - 1)

let gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

let pid = gl.createProgram();
shader(vert.textContent, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
shader(frag.textContent, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.linkProgram(pid);
gl.useProgram(pid);

let v = gl.getAttribLocation(pid, "v");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(v);

let timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'time');
let burstUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'burst');
let mouseUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(pid, 'mouse');

requestAnimationFrame(draw);

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  gl.uniform2f(mouseUniform, e.x/gl.drawingBufferWidth, 1-e.y/gl.drawingBufferHeight)
  active = true;
})

function draw(t) {
  if (active) {  
    burst = Math.min(1, burst+0.07)
    if (burst === 1) active = false;
  } else {
    burst = Math.max(0, burst-0.01)
  }
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, t/1000);
  gl.uniform1f(burstUniform, burst)
  // draw dots (every vertex)  
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, size*size);
  // draw lines
  for (var x=0; x<size; x++){  
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, x*size*8);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, size);  
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(v, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, (size)*8, x*8);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, size);  
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

function shader(src, type) {
  let sid = gl.createShader(type);
  gl.shaderSource(sid, src);
  gl.compileShader(sid);
  var message = gl.getShaderInfoLog(sid);
  gl.attachShader(pid, sid);
  if (message.length > 0) {
    console.log(src.split("\n").map((str, i) => (""+(1+i)).padStart(4, "0")+": "+str).join("\n"));
    throw message;
  }
}
</script>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```